# In Dockerfile how to copy file from network drive

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a file hosted (can't change that) at `//somenetwork/somefiles/myfile`

In my `Dockerfile` I would like to:

`COPY //somenetwork/somefiles/myfile /opt/files/file`

Is there anyway to achieve that with `Dockerfile`?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not easily, considering [ADD or COPY](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) uses the `Dockerfile` *context* (the current folder or below) to seek their resources.

It would be easier to `cp` that file first to the `Dockerfile` folder (before a `docker build .`), and leave in said `Dockerfile` a `COPY myfile /opt/files/file` directive.

Or you could run the container, and use a [`docker cp //somenetwork/somefiles/myfile /opt/files/file`](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) to add that file at rintime

Comment: wow thanks.  my project is usually composed out of : `project-base` `project-base/logic-project` ... `project-base/deployment-project` ... `project-base/project-systemtest` ... etc.. my docker is in `project-base/deployment-project` which means it cannot access any artifact from other projects!!! wow!!! I have to copy them into the deployment project! not nice! thanks!!!!